# How to install python libraries in docker file on ubuntu?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I want to create a docker image (*docker version:* `20.10.20`)that contains python libraires from a `requirement.txt` file that contains `50` libraries. Without facing root user permissions how can proceed. Here is the file:

```
From ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt install python3 -y
WORKDIR /Destop/DS

# COPY requirement.txt ./
# RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
# it contains only pandas==1.5.1

COPY script2.py ./
CMD ["python3", "./script2.py"]
```

It failed at requiremnt.txt command
**error* it takes lot of time while creating image.
because it ask for root permission.

Comment: How did it fail? Please provede the full error and traceback

Comment: as an FYI, you can just use one of the python images instead, see [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python)

Comment: You could have used a `python:3.7-alpine` base image in your `Dockerfile`  `FROM python:3.7-alpine` to save you from the hassle of writing separate service for `python` in your `docker-compose`. You dont need to use an `ubuntu` base image and the `docker-compose` could be cleaner that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me the only problem in your `Dockerfile` is in the line `RUN apt install python -y`. This is erroring with `Package 'python' has no installation candidate`.

It is expected since `python` refers to version 2.x of Python wich is deprecated and no longer present in the default Ubuntu repositories.

Changing your `Dockerfile` to use Python version 3.x worked fine for me.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt install python3 python3-pip -y
WORKDIR /Destop/DS

COPY requirement.txt ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirement.txt

COPY script2.py ./
CMD ["python3", "./script2.py"]
```

To test I used `requirement.txt`

```
pandas==1.5.1
```

and `script2.py`

```py
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)
```

With this building the docker image and running a container from it executed succesfully.

```bash
docker build -t myimage .
docker run --rm myimage
```

Comment: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root? while running ```apt install python3 python3-pip -y```

Comment: Which version of docker are you running? Please include the output of `docker info` in your original question

Comment: Docker version 20.10.20

Comment: Same here and no error... What is the ubuntu image you are using? it is `22.04` for me. What OS are you on?

Comment: it works now... i made few changes in ubuntu setting with ```%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```, ```%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL``` and changed docker command by adding sudo.